# Ansible - set external var as var name

Tags: ansible

Im using ansible 2.10.7

I need to set variable name in vars as a name i get from an external var:

```
---
- name: Playbook to demonstrate cv_container module.
  hosts: cvp_servers
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  collections:
    - arista.avd
    - arista.cvp
  vars:
    tag: "{{tag_name}}"
    configlet_list:
            {{some_var_name}}: "{{lookup('file', 'configlets/' + tag )}}"
```

It doesn't let me do it,
my playbook depends on the var name so i have to make it specific but also want the option to run it with different name, the var `{{some_var_name}}` has to be network device name that i run playbook for.

i have tried `"{{some_var_name}}"` , `'{{some_var_name}}'` It just doesn't work,

is it even possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the combine filter:

```
vars:
  configlet_list: "{{ {} | combine({ some_var_name: lookup('file', 'configlets/' + tag) }) }}"
```

Comment: Hey it didnt work:
`fatal: [ilhq]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ {} | combine( some_var_name: lookup('file', 'configlets/' + tag)) }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: template error while templating string: expected token ',', got ':'. String: {{ {} | combine( tag_name: lookup('file', 'configlets/' + tag)) }}"}` , also tried '{{some_var_name}}' and same

Comment: @BatchenRegev: Sorry, fogot the brackets inside the combine(), I've edited my answer